How can I display backtick in stackexchange?
I may be missing something very obvious.
I want to display this Mathematica line but have an issue with the backtick in the string being interpreted as end of a Mathematica quote
g=ImportString["WsnNFaUwKUQbAMRC_xxXKCl\dQz_{bsQ\ZHYDZpPFjn{SO", "Graph6"]`
jfyi: the string codes for a graph with $24$ vertices and $132$ edges and is one of $2$ graphs that is $R(4,5)$ with that many vertices and edges - actually no such graphs exists for more than $24$ vertices.

This question is off-topic.

Ask this in the Math Meta.
